# how to cancel or back up from google drive signin in iOS

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the standard OAuth2 viewControllerTouch for user login in my iOS app.  What are some ways to implement a "back" or "cancel" to return the UI to my app if the user gets frustrated and can't complete the login?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the sample included in [gtm-OAuth2](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/OAuth2SampleTouch). The short answer is when you create the controller you should be pushing it on to a navigation controller. The navigation bar should provide the back/cancel functionality.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  That sounds right.  I used the OAuth2 as in DrEdit, which uses a navigation controller, but doesn't push OAuth2 onto it.